# persp3d in ioslides in RStudio not shown

Tags: charts, 3d, rstudio

Is it possible to input persp3d chart into ioslides presentation in RStudio? I'm using the code below to plot log mortality rates over ages and years, but the chart is not shown.

Generating the chart outside the slides works. I would like to have an interactive chart in the presentation if possible.

````
```{R, echo = FALSE}
library(rgl)
library(demography)

# get data
plDemo<-hmd.mx("POL", username=username, password=password)

qxt <- log(plDemo$rate[[3]])
years <- plDemo$year
ages<- plDemo$age

persp3d(ages[0:100], years, qxt[0:100,], col="skyblue", shade=TRUE,xlab="Ages (0-100)",
    ylab="Years",zlab="Mortality rate (log)")
```
````

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: I have the same in a simple html output. Other 3d Objects appear. But I think at least you have to set `webgl=TRUE` in the chunk settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found an answer:

````
```{r setup, results='asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache=FALSE)
```
```{R, testgl, webgl=TRUE, echo=FALSE,  fig.height=5, warning=FALSE}
persp3d(ages[0:100], years, log(qxt)[0:100,], col="skyblue", shade=TRUE,xlab="Ages (0-100)",
        ylab="Years",zlab="Mortality rate (log)")
```
````